# Is it possible to use Image Preprocessing with image sequences?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I'm trying to use Keras' builtin image preprocessing capabilities to augment images in a sequence.
My dataset has the shape `(13200, 4, 168, 168, 1)` with 13200 sequences, each consisting of 4 168x168px grayscale images.

When trying to run `datagen.flow()` on my dataset I get:

```
ValueError: ('Input data in `NumpyArrayIterator` should have rank 4. You passed an array with shape', (13200, 4, 168, 168, 1))
```

I'm assuming `ImageDataGenerator` is not able to handle my sequences of 4 images per sample correctly. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What your `y` looks like?

Comment: `y.shape = (13200, 250)` because I have 250 classes.

Comment: Ok - so my answer should be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to define a new generator by:

```
def sequence_image_generator(x, y, batch_size, generator, seq_len=4):
    new_y = numpy.repeat(y, seq_len, axis = 0)
    helper_flow = generator.flow(x.reshape((x.shape[0] * seq_len,
                                            x.shape[2],
                                            x.shape[3],
                                            x.shape[4])),
                                 new_y,
                                 batch_size=seq_len * batch_size)
    for x_temp, y_temp in helper_flow:
        yield x_temp.reshape((x_temp.shape[0] / seq_len, 
                              seq_len, 
                              x.shape[2],
                              x.shape[3],
                              x.shape[4])), y_temp[::seq_len,:]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I run it I get: `ValueError: X (images tensor) and y (labels) should have the same length.` so I added `axis=0` to the `numpy.repeat()`.
Now I get `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged` for the last line containing the `yield` statement. Do you have any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Try now. (`y_temp[::seq_len,:]`)

Comment: Same error. While debugging I found that it's actually the first part (reshaping `x_temp`) that's causing the error.

Comment: Aah - ok. I forgot about annoying part of `imageGenerator`. try now.

Comment: Had to put `int()` around `x_temp.shape[0] / seq_len` and now it finally works. Thank you so much, Marcin!

Comment: this function doesn't use the same transformation for all images of the same sequence. do you have another solution to do the same transformation to all image in same sequence

Comment: Do you have a solution for creating image sequence batches for fit_generator?